# How prove this the equation $f'(x)+f(x)=0$ has at least one root in $(a,b)$

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f$ is continous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$,and such
$$f(a)+f(b)=0$$
show that: then the equation $f'(x)+f(x)=0$ has at least one root in $(a,b)$

My try: not
$$(e^xf(x))'=e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$$

But I can't,Thank you

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1 - x$ then $f(0) + f(2) = 0$, but $f'(x) + f(x) = -x$ and this is non zero on $(0, 2)$

Comment: It is strange that people don't even verify the question and start rating it.

Comment: Are there counterexamples also if the interval for the roots includes $a$ and $b$?

Comment: same example in interval $[1/2, 3/2]$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check your question. I believe there is a mistake. If $f(x) = 1 - x$ then $f(0) + f(2) = 0$ and $f'(x) + f(x) = -x$ which is non-zero in $(0, 2)$ so this serves as a counterexample. Please check the source of the question and re-write it.

Comment: Are there counterexamples also if the interval for the roots includes $a$ and $b$?

Comment: yes Daniel the same example in interval $[1/2, 3/2]$. You should have guessed this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't care much for the attitude though, but never mind...